# How to validate the given parameters format,based on the parameters format will be executing the different script

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu

How to validate the given parameters format,based on the parameters format will be executing the different script.
Ex: I have script.sh and passing the to arguments with two different formats(one is Date arguments and another one is ids), I just wants to check date format, not exactly the date, I checked with below script but did not work in Ubuntu and rhel.

```
...
    #!/usr/bin/bash
    Para1=$1
    Para2=$2
     if [[ $Para1 =~ ^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$ ] && [ $Para2 =~ ^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$ ] ]     
     then 
     Echo "execute blah blah.."
   else
    if [[ $Para1 =~ ^[0-9a-zA-Z]{9}$ ] && [ $Para2 =~ ^[0-9a-zA-Z]{9}$ ] ]          
       then
       echo "execute the script"
        else `enter code here`
          echo "please pass the right ids.
    fi
    fi  
...
```

Please let Me know anything missing.

Comment: You have syntax errors. The correct syntax is `[[ $Para1 =~ ^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$ && $Para2 =~ ^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$ ]]` for the first `if` and `[[ $Para1 =~ ^[0-9a-zA-Z]{9}$ && $Para2 =~ ^[0-9a-zA-Z]{9}$ ]]` for the second.

Comment: In the future, save  yourself time by pasting your script into https://shellcheck.net . It flagged these issues with a clear error message. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks @M.NejatAydi and shellter